# DOM object not yet created (TypeError: undefined) with Capybara, PhantomJS test

Tags: javascript, jquery, tdd, capybara, phantomjs

I have written some javascript code that when a button is clicked, it does the following code (this is only a part of a method, there's some code before and after this line. video_id is set somewhere above this line).

```
var data_url = $('.BrightcoveExperience').attr('data').replace(/(videoPlayer=)[^\&]+/, '$1' + video_id);
```

The code works when I tested it in a browser.  There's no console error.

However, my automated Cucumber test (Capybara with PhantomJS) fails with the following error message

```
One or more errors were raised in the Javascript code on the page. If you don't care about these errors, you can ignore them by setting js_errors: false in your Poltergeist configuration (see documentation for details).

TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '$('.BrightcoveExperience').attr('data').replace')
```

Basically `$('.BrightcoveExperience').attr('data')` returns `undefined` in my automated test
for some reason.

If I rewrite my code to the following, the test would pass.

```
var brightcove_url = $('.BrightcoveExperience').attr('data')
if (typeof brightcove_url !== 'undefined') {
    brightcove_url = brightcove_url.replace(/(videoPlayer=)[^\&]+/, '$1' + video_id);
}
```

I believe this is caused by a race condition.  Somehow in automated test, when I click on the button, in the click event code, the DOM object `$('.BrightcoveExperience')` is not created yet.  So some kind of delay or wait should be introduced.

But how?

Thanks

Comment: $('.BrightcoveExperience') is a class-based selector. it returns an array of DOM elements with the class "BrightcoveExperience". If you then do a .attr('data') on it, it only handles the first element of that array. If that first element does not have an attribute named "data", it's undefined and throws an error. It's possible that Capybara/Poltergeist don't properly assign data a value.

Answer (score 1):

Try to check `length` of your element like,

```
if($('.BrightcoveExperience').length){
    var brightcove_url = $('.BrightcoveExperience').attr('data')
    // you code here
}
```

Comment: I think the question is why $('.BrightcoveExperience') does NOT return meaningful data in automated test, but does in a browser.  Is it poltergeist?  Do I need to put a sleep somewhere in the test?  Do I need a different way to access the DOM element?  Thank you.